# Unnecessary imports in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, import, eclipse-cdt

I converted from GCC 3.4.2 to 4.8.1 but my projects in Eclipse still leave the imports, and those imports also show as warnings in the source code. I can't find any way to remove them manually and those folders don't exist on the filesystem. How do I fix this?

Here is an illustration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQpIH.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Goto Project *'Properties->C++ General->Path & Symbols Includes'* Tab and remove those path entries there, respectively change them to your new installation paths.

Another place to look might be *'Properties->C++ General->Preprocessor Include Pathes'*, if there are project specific entries for these pathes.

Comment: 'Path & Symbols Includes' seems to be empty and the options in 'Preprocessor Include Paths' are grayed. http://i.imgur.com/ynD7OvZ.jpg

Comment: _'and the options in 'Preprocessor Include Paths' are grayed'_ Then you'll have to set them via project specific options maybe. But I've noticing when researching that it's hard to find how Eclipse CDT refers to a particular toolchanin. May be you'd be better off to import your project by source import.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by deleting the .metadata folder in the workspace directory and reimporting the project. I had to reconfigure Eclipse but at least it works now. Thanks for the suggestions.